# ui-calendar displaying all events in all-day allDay not working

Tags: json, cordova, fullcalendar

I have Fullcalendar working in my cordova application and I am trying to use the agendaWeek view, but whenever the event renders it is in the all-day section. I have added allDay to the JSON data and set it to false but that still has not fixed the issue.

Event script:

```
    $scope.eventSources = [
{
    events: function(start, end, callback) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url/calendarConnect.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) 
            {
                var events = [];
                $(response.events).each(function() 
                {
                    events.push
                        ({
                        id: $(this).attr('ID'),
                        class_id: $(this).attr('class_id'),
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start'),
                        end: $(this).attr('end'),
                        allDay: $(this).attr('allDay')
                        });
                });
                var userTable = $.grep(events, function (a)
                {
                    return a.class_id == $scope.Current.currentUser;
                });
                callback(userTable);
            }    
        });
    }
}
]
```

JSON String:

```
{"success":1,"message":"Details Available!","events":
[{"ID":"1","title":"Example Class  12345","start":"2014-08-29 09:00:00","class_id":"12345","end":"2014-08-29 17:00:00","allDay":"false"},
{"ID":"2","title":"Example Class 53870","start":"2014-08-13 00:00:00","class_id":"53870","end":"2014-08-13 00:00:00","allDay":"false"},
{"ID":"3","title":"Example Event ","start":"2014-08-13 12:00:00","class_id":"54321","end":"2014-08-13 13:00:00","allDay":"false"},
{"ID":"11","title":"Testing 123","start":"2014-08-13 00:00:00","class_id":"19224","end":"2014-08-13 23:59:00","allDay":"false"},
{"ID":"12","title":"Test Class Sept","start":"2014-09-23 13:00:00","class_id":"53870","end":"2014-09-23 14:00:00","allDay":"false"},
{"ID":"14","title":"Employ ability Skills w\/J","start":"2014-09-12 07:00:00","class_id":"53870","end":"2014-09-12 09:00:00","allDay":"false"}]}
```

I'm not all that familiar with this plugin and nothing I have read is working for me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

*Update*: I'm presuming it has to do with the fact that "allDay" is being returned in "" therefore is being interpreted as a string, how would I go about changing that in the php?

Answer (score 0):

One fix, at the sacrifice to change it on the server side is to have allDay set to false in the array. This is a potential sollution but not the answer to my issue. The problem is because the response of "false" is being interpreted as a string, if you can remove the "" then it should work.